# Learning Python for web development. Python 2 or 3?

Tags: web-applications, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am a quite experienced PHP developer (using OOP features where possible) and currently searching for another language to play with. I've used Ruby, Python and Node and found Python to be the best choice so far (in terms of maturity, ease of use and the learning curve). As I am mostly focusing on web centric development Django seems to be the obvious framework of choice. But here is my question: Django is still based on Python 2, as is Flask but nearly every Python tutorial out there suggests you to start learning Python 3. But it seems that version 2 is the one you have to start with if you want to use the more popular web frameworks and that doesn't seem to change any time soon. Is this true? Do you know alternatives?

I know there are similar questions like that but they are either outdated or not focused on web development so I guess this is a valid one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Web does indeed lag behind a bit, so yes Python 2 is still what you want for web development, although more and more frameworks support Python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a Python framework for web development, I would highly recommend using Django. Regarding Python 2 or 3 issue, Python 3 is of course the future. Django will soon be migrated to Python 3. For now you can stick with Django and Python 2.7. But avoid using those features of Python 2.7 which are removed from Python 3.

Comment: Thanks. Can't upvote as I don't have > 15 points :) I've seen that Django 1.5 is Python 3 compatible but this still is a RC and for experienced users only, so probably not a good start for a newbie like me. So I guess I'll just have fun hacking around with both versions to get a feeling on how Python works. Thanks again!